# 温度分布画像予測の誤差の単位を温度に対応させたい

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, 画像処理

**問題**
私はある温度分布を予測して、その出力が本来の温度分布とどれだけ誤差があるのか調べたいと思っています。例として日本の陸地の温度を予測したいとします。添付する画像において上の画像が本来の画像、下の画像が予測した画像だとします。黒いところが26度、灰色のところが25度、非常に分かりにくいですがその右の薄い灰色を24度と考えてください。すると誤差があると思います。これが単位を温度としてどれだけの誤差があるのかを数値化しようと考えているのですが、その方法が分かりません。尚その誤差を出す時に、海の部分は誤差を出す際に計算に入れないようにして、陸地部分のみでの誤差を出したいです。

**これまでに試した事**
取り敢えず類似率を出しました。類似率は1以下とし、全く同じ場合は1が出力される様にしました。同じ場合でない場合は例えば0.56869といった様な出力がされる様にしました。該当コードを以下に記述します。

```
import cv2
import os

TARGET_FILE = '05.png'
IMG_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/images/'
IMG_SIZE = (200, 200)

target_img_path = IMG_DIR + TARGET_FILE
target_img = cv2.imread(target_img_path)
target_img = cv2.resize(target_img, IMG_SIZE)
target_hist = cv2.calcHist([target_img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

print('TARGET_FILE: %s' % (TARGET_FILE))

files = os.listdir(IMG_DIR)
for file in files:
    if file == '.DS_Store' or file == TARGET_FILE:
        continue

    comparing_img_path = IMG_DIR + file
    comparing_img = cv2.imread(comparing_img_path)
    comparing_img = cv2.resize(comparing_img, IMG_SIZE)
    comparing_hist = cv2.calcHist([comparing_img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

    ret = cv2.compareHist(target_hist, comparing_hist, 0)
    print(file, ret)
```

しかしこれでは誤差の単位が無く、これを全体的にどれだけの温度の誤差があるのか（例えばこの2枚を比較した際に0.27788度誤差があるの様に）を出力する様にしたいと考えています。

**実現したい事**
下の2枚の画像において陸地部分の温度の誤差がどれだけあるか、誤差の単位を温度で出力する方法をご教示いただけますでしょうか。それには先ず黒いところが26度、灰色のところが25度、薄い灰色が24度であるという事を含めないといけないと思います。無知で大変申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。
＊今回は一例として示す為に以下から画像を取得しました。[リンク](https://www.jma.go.jp/jma/kishou/know/suikei_kishou/kaisetsu.html)この画像をグレースケール画像に変換したものを、添付した画像としています。この添付した画像での温度の誤差を示したいと考えてください。
[image: 本来の画像]

[image: 予測した画像]

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**
言語：Python
環境：Windows10
ブラウザ：Google Chrome（Google Colaboratory)
＊ノートパソコンです。全て最新バージョンです。プログラミング中はcolab以外のタブ、アプリは開いていません。
＊急を要する為、こちらのサイトでも同内容の質問をしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/aerlw5zu94r2gm

Comment: 「誤差」や「類似率」という言葉(それが引き起こす雰囲気)の選び方が上手くなくて迷走しているのでは？ 単に予測と実測の差を示せば簡単になるのではないでしょうか？ 同じ値なら 0、予測が1度高ければ +1、予測が1度低ければ －1 (高低と＋－は逆でも良いでしょう)で、差が大きければ数値の絶対値も大きくなるとすれば、ヒートマップを作成するのと同じ手法がそのまま使えるのでは？ 表示に使われている画像を元に作業しようとしているように見えますが、画像を作る元になった予測および実測のデータを使うのが一番速くて確実だと思われます。

Comment: 検討します。後、実際に使用するものも気象庁の様な画像になります。よって画像を作る元になったデータは数字ではなく、画像になります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決です。以下に2値化画像取得プログラムと誤差取得プログラムを示します。
1：2値化

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pylab import * #imshowが無いというエラー防止

img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/mask_before.png",0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 168, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)#1つめの数以上の画素値は２つ目の数の画素値にする
thresh[thresh > 0] = 255 # 0以外は255に
cv2.imwrite("/content/drive/MyDrive/mask.png", thresh)
```

2：誤差

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

TARGET_FILE = 'target.PNG'
#print(TARGET_FILE)
IMG_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname("__file__")) + '/drive/MyDrive/images/'#imagesフォルダの中にあるファイルが比較対象
print(IMG_DIR)
#IMG_SIZE = (312, 312)

target_img_path = IMG_DIR + TARGET_FILE #比較対象を足す
target_img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/images/target.PNG",0)
print(target_img)
#target_img = cv2.resize(target_img, IMG_SIZE)
#target_hist = cv2.calcHist([target_img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256]) #ヒストグラムを出す際に使う

#target_img = int(target_img_origin)
target_img[target_img <= 36] = 26
target_img[((target_img >= 37) & (target_img <= 139))] = 25
target_img[((target_img >= 140) & (target_img <= 224))] = 24
target_img[target_img >= 225] = 23

print('TARGET_FILE: %s' % (TARGET_FILE)) #%sは文字列出力に使う、ターゲットファイルはどのpngファイルか

#img_diff = cv2.diff(TARGET_FILE, IMG_DIR) #diffで差分の計算を行う
#plt.imshow(img_diff)

#img_diff = cv2.cvtColor(img_diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
mask_img = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/mask.png",0)
print(mask_img) #Noneが返ってきたらファイルが存在していないので、これで確かめる
mask_img[mask_img > 0] = 1 # 0以外は1に
files = os.listdir(IMG_DIR) #ディレクトリとファイルの一覧を取得
for file in files:
    if file == '.DS_Store' or file == TARGET_FILE:
        continue

    comparing_img_path = IMG_DIR + file
    comparing_img = cv2.imread(comparing_img_path,0)

    comparing_img[comparing_img<=36] = 26
    comparing_img[((comparing_img>=37) & (comparing_img<=139))] = 25
    comparing_img[((comparing_img>=140) & (comparing_img<=224))] = 24
    comparing_img[comparing_img>=225] = 23

    img_diff = target_img.astype(int) - comparing_img.astype(int)
    print(img_diff.max())
    print(img_diff.min())

    print((img_diff * mask_img).sum() / mask_img.sum())
    print(np.average(img_diff, weights=mask_img))

    print(np.abs(img_diff * mask_img).sum() / mask_img.sum())
    print(np.average(np.abs(img_diff), weights=mask_img))
```